# Flutter - Image to string base64?

Tags: image, flutter, dart

I want to convert a Image to String(base64). Not a file but a image no matter where it came from:

```dart
Image logo = Image.network("https://image.image.webp");
Image logo = Image.asset("assets/image.jpg");
Image logo = Image.file("/sdcard/DCIM/image.png");
Image logo = Image.memory(idk);
Image logo = Image(idk);
```

Ive read many articles but they always only showed how to convert an File which contains a Image to base64.
for example:
[image to base64](https://bezkoder.com/dart-base64-image/)

Answer (score 0):

This method can work, but it needs to be verified for performance.

```
var stream = logo.image.resolve(createLocalImageConfiguration(context));
stream.addListener(ImageStreamListener((imageInfo, _) async {
    var byteData = await imageInfo.image.toByteData( format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    var data = byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes);
    base64Encode(data);
}));
```